# Places API types

Tags: google-places-api

I am creating a travel website with 2 apps and am getting mixed results from the Places API.

My results include cities and countries which is fine, however, there are also local communities, city districts, US states and other not so relevant results available which I would rather have excluded. Is it feasible to do so?

Ideally, it would be of great help if there was a way to lookup the type of places that could be sourced from the API, for me to review and inform my developers which I would like to include.

Any help on this topic would be strongly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Thomas

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous request, we tried using several destination 'types' offered by the Google Places API but none seem to provide the ideal type of results we require for our platforms. 

We tried various URLs with parameter 'type' set to either '(regions)' or 'geocode' but still the results include destination types that may not be perceived useful by the users.

If there is a possibility to modify the API such that certain 'types'
of results would appear only, then this would help our app a lot.

Could someone maybe give us some advise on how to achieve what we intend to do?

Answer (score 0):

At this point the best list of supported data types returned by our APIs is listed on [Supported Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types).